# Android : can't stop handler when runs progress bar dialog

Tags: android, handler, progressdialog

I make a dialog based on this website http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-progress-bar-example/

When progress bar goes to 100%, dialog closed but a toast still appears continuously. I noticed that after bar goes to 100%, progressHandler still runs looping.

How can I solved this problem?
Thing that I want : When progress bar goes to 100% then dialog closed and Toast shows and closed.

```
Thread background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void run() {
try {

    while (dialog.getProgress() <= dialog.getMax()) {
    // wait 500ms between each update
    Thread.sleep(100);
    // active the update handler
    progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
}


} catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
    // if something fails do something smart
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Occurs",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
});

// start the background thread
background.start();
}

// handler for the background updating
Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    dialog.incrementProgressBy(increment);

    if(dialog.getProgress()==100){
    editor.putInt("lastestSummaryNoSent",summary.getCurrentSummaryNo());
    editor.commit();
    dialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update Finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

is because of the Toast you have provided inside the **background** Thread. Remove the Toast inside the Catch phrase and you will be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, this is my mistake with the question. The corrected question is that there is not any error with my code, it can be run on emulator. So, I deleted error description already. Sorry for my mistake but thanks for your help very much :)